# NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, primary-key, django-urls

So i was trying to make a simple Update Profile app But when i try to accesses the Update Page i have to Write the link Manually + the id in this case is 2 for example 'accounts/update/2' else it wouldn't work when i try to use "{% url 'edit_user' %}" i get this

```
`NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'edit_user' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/update/(?P<pk>\\d+)/']`
```

url.py

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', main_views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^uprofile$', main_views.uprofile, name='uprofile'),
url(r'^accounts/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/', User_Profile_views.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

views.py

```
@login_required() # only logged in users should access this
def edit_user(request, pk):
    # querying the User object with pk from url
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # prepopulate UserProfileForm with retrieved user values from above.
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

    # The sorcery begins from here, see explanation below
    ProfileInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile, fields=('website', 'bio', 'phone', 'city', 'country', 'organization'))
    formset = ProfileInlineFormset(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=created_user)

                if formset.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile/')

        return render(request, "account/account_update.html", {
            "noodle": pk,
            "noodle_form": user_form,
            "formset": formset,
        })
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

html form

```
<div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="flow-text">Update your information</h2>
          <form action="." method="POST" class="padding">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ noodle_form.as_p }}
            <div class="divider"></div>
            {{ formset.management_form }}
                {{ formset.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-light waves-effect"><i class="large material-icons">done</i></button>
            <a href="#" onclick="window.history.back(); return false;" title="Cancel" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">history</i></a>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `{% url 'edit_user' %}` anywhere in code you posted.

Comment: that's True Since i used it in the Navbar Located in base.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, edit_user needs a parameter: the id of the user to edit. You need to pass that in the `url` tag.

```
{% url 'edit_user' pk=my_user.pk %}
```

or whatever the name of your user object is.

Comment: thanks mate {% url 'edit_user' pk=user.pk %} solved it